# Pros and Cons of multiple IBM queue managers vs. single IBM queue manager

Tags: queue, ibm-mq

Assuming that there are 10 queues needs to be created. What are the pros and cons of configuring:

1. Ten IBM MQ queue managers, each of which will manage 1 single queue
2. One single IBM MQ queue manager which will manage all 10 queues.

In terms of IBM MQ best practices, which one is recommended?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There are probably more than 2 correct answers (being (1) One queue manager and (2) Many queue managers).  But if all you need is 10 (even unrelated) queue objects, then 1 queue manager is probably the best/better way to go.

Many times queue objects and their channels are split up based on one of or a combiniation of, the following list of inclusive considerations and/or requirements (in no particular order):

- internal facing vs customer/partner facing
- message throughput sizing
- security
- application grouping
- major business unit
- isolation
- criticality of availability
- supporting architecture
- corporate compliance
- network architecture
- storage infrastructure

I could probably go on .... but I won't.

Simply put .... there is no simple answer.  Sorry if this does not help.

Answer (score 2):

I found an article from IBM MQ mentioning following best practice

"For architectural as well as performance reasons, it is usually better to create one queue manager with 100 queues as opposed to 100 queue managers with one queue apiece. Where it makes sense, try to limit the number of queue managers in an MQ environment. A single queue manager per server can usually fulfill the needs of all of the queues and applications on that server"

Answer (score 1):

10 queues is such a tiny number, that you can just go with one queue manager no problem. It gets interesting when you want, say, 10,000 queues.